# how do i return the array from method?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I am a beginner of programming, hope that anyone can help me solve my problem, please

```
public int [][]matrixSetup(String size, char i) throws IOException {

  int size_num = Integer.parseInt(size);

  if (size_num > 1 && size_num < 4) {   
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


     System.out.println("input the value store them, they arrange as" + i + "11,"+ i+ "12," + i +"21,"+ i +"22 etc");

     for(int row = 0; row < size_num ; row++)
        for(int col = 0 ; col < size_num ; col++){
            int [][]A = new int [size_num][size_num];
            String ipS = br.readLine();                     //ipS = input String
            int input_value = Integer.parseInt(ipS);
            A[row][col] = input_value;          
        }
  } else System.out.println("invalid matrix size!");
  return A; //How to return the matrix?
}
```

Comment: its a java language,

Comment: You're creating a new array for each iteration. You should create A outside of your loops.

Comment: Learn about [variable scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Comment: could you please give me some example, i have google and can not find any idea.

Comment: Language tag spam -- Please don't do this again.

Comment: sorry, i am first time to use...

Comment: Your array is out of scope when you try to return it. For a complete definition of scopes in java, see [jls-6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3).  In particular, look at Example 6.3-2. Scope of Local Variable Declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question "How to return the matrix": you are already doing it the right way. As you can see from the comments so far, the problem lies in the declaration of `A`.

`A` is declared and initialized inside the `for`-loop:

```
int [][]A = new int [size_num][size_num];
```

Hence its visibility is limited to the `for`-loop. To make `A` visible to the already existing `return` statement you have to move its declaration:

```
int size_num = Integer.parseInt(size);
int[][]  A = new int[size_num][size_num];
if (size_num > 1 && size_num < 4) {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  for(int row = 0; row < size_num ; row++)
    for(int col = 0 ; col < size_num ; col++){
        String ipS = br.readLine();
        int input_value = Integer.parseInt(ipS);
        A[row][col] = input_value;
  }
} else {
  System.out.println("invalid matrix size!");
}
return A;
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan Freitag